# Parent webpage jumps / autoscrolls to an iframe location when content within iframe transitions using #pageName

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, iframe

Parent webpage jumps / autoscrolls to location of iframe when transition happens within an iframe. Transition happens using jquery mobile - $.mobile.changePage($(#pageName)) [ using an anchor to transition to a div ].

I have gone through various links on stackoverflow e.g., [Loading iframe with an #element specified moves the parent viewpoint to the same location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465378/loading-iframe-with-an-element-specified-moves-the-parent-viewpoint-to-the-same)  (hiding iframe till it loads and page changes but it doesn't solve the issue)

There were few other links that mentioned a) About window.parent scrollToTop when iframe loads but I do not want the parent page to scroll at all when page within an iframe changes. b) Changing focus to parent page when iframe loads but it didn't help too. (Note page transitions to another div in an iframe so it seems we need to use anchor tags as per jquery mobile).  Is their a way to stop this parent page autoscrolling ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was jQuery mobile's focusPage, which was autofocusing content within an iframe. To change this behavior - I added below mentioned javascript in  of webpage displayed within an iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (self != top) { //if inside iframe
        //don't use focusPage for embedded site to prevent autoscroll
            $.mobile.focusPage = function ( page ) {
            return;
                }
        }
</script>
```

Note: This link helped in resolving this issue : [When within iframe JQuery Mobile autoscrolls to the iframe top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359295/when-within-iframe-jquery-mobile-autoscrolls-to-the-iframe-top)